# I am trying to build an Android apk for google play console. When I run

Tags: android, flutter, build, flutter-dependencies, dependency-management

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1156
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildRelease'.

> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 45s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                          107.3s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
PS C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\ct\gorun\gitlab\apps\wazeto-user>

tried flutter clean, flutter pub get this didn't worked. then i went for flutter pub upgrade --major-versions ... still shows the same error after flutter build apk

Answer (score 0):

that happens sometimes because some issues wrong in the flutter sdk **try to download the sdk again and replase with the current**. or toggle the version with the FVM tool.
it will build with you and if you use for example 2.10.0 you can use also 2.10.3 it also will work.